# Pass data from repository to View Model without any third-party

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, viewmodel, android-livedata

I want to return the data from the repository to the viewmodel without using any third-party

```
    class MyRepository{
        
    // Some code that return the data from webservice
        
}


class MyViewModel:ViewModel(){
    
init{
    val repo= MyRepository()
    MyRepository.getData()
}
    
    //I need a way to operate on the data that I get from repository
    
    }
```

ViewModel call -> Repoistory get the data-> ViewModel do operation on the data

With no third-parties library .. just the android studio SDK.

Comment: Could you provide more information? With what you wrote it would be as simple as making an instance of the repository on the view model and perform the method calls

Comment: Sergio Pardo My problem not with calling the repository, my problem with getting the data from repository when finished to viewmodel.

Comment: Do you mean like with an asynchronous job?

Comment: @SergioPardo After repository get the data from webservice I want to pass this data to view model without using any third-party like Rx or coroutines or etc..

Comment: Got it, let me explain a way for you to do that as an answer

Comment: I appreciate your effort ..waiting for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callbacks to be notified when a work is done. The way to do it would be to pass the view model as a parameter to the method that will perform the work. I recommend you to define an interface so the repository does not rely directly on the view model but rather an interface.

The solution would look something like:

```
interface WebServiceCallback {
    fun onWebServiceSuccess(data: MyObject)
    fun onWebServiceError(error: MyError)
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel(), WebServiceCallback {

    init {
        val repo = MyRepository()
        repo.getData(this)
    }

    override fun onWebServiceSuccess(data: MyObject) {
        //Implementation of what to do on success
    }

    override fun onWebServiceError(error: MyError) {
        //Implementation of what to do on failure
    }
}

class MyRepository { 
    fun getData(callback: WebServiceCallback) {
        //Do your service call however you have implemented it
        if(serviceResponse.isSuccess() == true) {
            callback.onWebServiceSuccess(serviceResponse.data)
        } else {
            callback.onWebServiceError(serviceResponse.error)
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will call the respective methods on the view model after you have completed the work on the repo. Hope this answer it's helpful to you.

Comment: Very good, I have another question I'm using HttpUrlConnection to get the data from webservice because as I said it must solved without any third-party so how can I know that HttpUrlConnection finish and get the data to pass it to success or error ?

Comment: I can refer you to this documentation since it's very complete, it's to implement a POST but is practically the same if you need another REST operation. https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android

Comment: Very good .. and very thanks I took your time, so I apologize and thanks for your effort

Comment: Can I ask a last question :D 
how can I inject the view model and repository and any class without using dagger or koin .. again with just Android SDK ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Given that case you would have to implement your own dependency injection, but wouldn't be able to use annotations without having to develop a robust library such as the ones you mentioned. I think the easiest way to achieve something similar would be to implement your own service locator, this is basically a singleton that will hold all the instances of your dependencies and then you would have there the way to instantiate all your classes , if you have a view model that has a dependency on a repository you would call the instance within the same service locator.

Comment: @SergioPardo Is this approach of communicating a Repository with a ViewModel recommended in some place on the Android Architecture documentation? I just want to know if this is a clean way of doing this kind of tasks, if not, which would be the alternatives to notify a ViewModel about something from the Repository?